# am getting sub-process error code everytime am installing any kind of tool

Tags: kali-linux, dpkg

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-16 (--configure):

dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-kali2-amd64

Errors were encountered while processing:
openssh-server
dictionaries-common
nginx-common
samba-common
tex-common
wamerican
postgresql-common
libapache2-mod-php8.2
libpam-systemd:amd64
sane-utils
postgresql-15
cryptsetup-initramfs
postgresql-16

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Did you install using `dpkg` or via `apt` or some other way? What is the complete command you are using?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linusecurityx distribution geared towards various information tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux system. This is unwise. Rather, install a supported Ubuntu release. You can build or install any of the tools.